# Microsoft Access 2007 running a query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am running a query on Microsoft Access 2007. I am trying to use multiple tables. Once the query is run, data shown in the report is duplicated and wrong. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: We need more information to help. Can you post the query? How about a small example table and the output that comes from that?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have not linked the tables and are getting a *cartesian product* (all possible outcomes).

In the query page, try dragging the linking fields (foreign, or primary keys) from one table to another and you will see a line drawn. This means that the tables will link where the field values (and data types) are equal, and you should end up with the result you expect.

Understanding this is key to the use of relational databases and can be a bit tricky to grasp in the early days.

Hop this helps as a start point.

If not, then please post more information.